# Node.js: How to pass route parameters while specifying a url in an AJAX POST request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a post route in a node application like so,

```
app.post('/portfolio/:name/:id/:comment_parent', function(req, res){
  ...
});
```

Inside the callback body, I save an entry into mySQL database. I need the route params since they go as a column entry to my database. Now I want to make the whole process asynchronous using AJAX, but after searching on the internet I found no good way of passing route params to the `url` attribute of an AJAX POST request. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using the ajax script inside my ejs template. That way I can directly append the route params to the url. The main problem was to send these parameters from ejs to my js file, using a script tag in the ejs itself helped with this.